# Measuring integration test coverage of .NET Core app

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, code-coverage

I would like to measure integration test coverage of a ASP.NET Core application running in a Linux container.

Tooling like [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) works nicely when applied to a unit test project that links system under test directly, but does not seems to support the case of measuring coverage of code running at separate machine.